How to import a PNG signature into Adobe Acrobat Reader?
I've been trying to import my signature stored as a .png file into Adobe Acrobat Reader to sign PDF documents, but I can't find the "Add Signature" option. I've looked under "Fill & Sign" and even the "Sign" icon, but still no luck.

               

here is what I expected to see from the official website:

               

I've tried this on both Windows 10 and macOS with the latest version of Adobe Acrobat Reader. What steps should I follow to resolve this issue? Is there something I might be missing?

Acrobat Reader has a lot of features from PRO needed for XFA and signed filling, but they present different restrictions depending on context.
Normally for signing with image the "image" must have been at one time stored as a PDF stamp, not a PNG (True PNG is not actually a valid PDF object, as it was introduced as 2 bitmaps, later in a workaround fashion!).

To initiate signing it helps to have a "sign here" annotation field in the PDF to be signed. This example is pure plain text that Acrobat sees as a requirement for signing.


However in many cases you can without that use the Sign yourself feature with previous stored image signatures.

Beware if you sign a PDF the existing ability to sign the other party box is locked out as the file should then be sealed as valid. (Never agree to a PDF where somebody else can make changes after you sign, but then they can delete your signature anyway and replace yours with theirs.)

Answer
When a suitable document is opened Adobe Reader will allow you personally only one signature and one initials. So you may need to delete any previously stored entries.

You need to select image option and preferably store initials too.

When asked for a signature image you can add a PNG which will be converted into PDF objects.


wait, what? I'm only allowed to add one single signature and one single initial. Why though?

Thanks a lot for your kind support. With this information and the fact that Adobe thinks it is my master to decide what I can or can't do with my computer, I am going to stop using Adobe products even less than before.
